# About FBX binary file format

Tags: c, opengl

I want to read FBX binary format, but I want to not use FBX sdk of Autodesk.

Please teach when someone knows that web sites of fbx binary file format.

Comment: Try this: https://code.blender.org/2013/08/fbx-binary-file-format-specification/

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX - Blender includes a Python script for export to FBX format. This is probably the closest thing you'll find for documentation of it. Sounds like a painful task of RTFS.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the FBX binary format is undocumented.

At the moment I'm working on a loader though based on work by `assimp`, Both parsers are roughly equivalent.

https://github.com/ideasman42/pyfbx_i42 / https://github.com/ideasman42/pyfbx_i42/blob/master/pyfbx/parse_bin.py

https://github.com/assimp/assimp / https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/FBXBinaryTokenizer.cpp

I wrote `pyfbx` which is a standalone Python3 port of the C++ library which is apart of assimp and includes an example tool `fbx2json`.

Note that these only parse the data, giving you something like XML/JSON (a tree typed data), but you still need to make sense of this. I managed to get a mesh importer working in couple of hours, but if you want materials, animation etc, this is more work.